# Composer update breaks the website Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I accidentally run composer update which breaks my website. I am using Laravel 5.2. Now, I am getting this error

```
  ErrorException in EventServiceProvider.php line 8:
 Declaration of 
 App\Providers\ 
 EventServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Contracts\Events\ Dispatcher $events) should be compatible with 
  Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot()
```

I tries to remove arguments from EventServiceProvider like this

```
  /**
 * Register any other events for your application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    //
}
```

EventServiceProvider before changes:

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Providers;

  use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as 
  ServiceProvider;

 class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
 {
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\EventListener',
    ],
];
   /**
 * Register any other events for your application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
 * @return void
 */
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    //
}
```

and from RouteServiceProvider.php

```
 /**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //

    parent::boot();
}
```

RouteServiceProvider before changes:

```
   <?php

   namespace App\Providers;

   use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as 
   ServiceProvider;

  class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
  {
/**
 * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
 *
 * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';


  /**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
 * @return void
 */
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    //

    parent::boot($router);
}
```

Now, I am getting this error:
      BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
      Method controllers does not exist.
[image]

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: What's your current version of laravel and what was your previous (if you remember)? Also post the full `EventServiceProvider.php` without the changes after update.

Comment: I have edited the question, please check

Comment: I need to see the complete class, not just the boot method. I might know what the issue is. Need to confirm.

Comment: I am sorry. I just edited it. Please check

Comment: Can you check the framework version from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php` and post it? It should be something like `const VERSION = '5.4.23';`. I see no issues with your providers from 5.2 branch perspective.

Comment: No, its /**
     * The Laravel framework version.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const VERSION = '5.3.31';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145775/discussion-between-sandeesh-and-aisha-kamran).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and discussion, you've somehow ended up updating your Laravel framework to 5.3.31 which has breaking changes with 5.2. The solution would to be to either downgrade to the latest version under 5.2 or upgrade the complete application to 5.3 following the upgrade guide.

To fix with the downgrade replace the current framework package in `composer.json` with `"laravel/framework": "5.2.*",` and run `composer update`

Comment: The solution works perfectly fine. Thank you. You saved my day.